# Почему не получаю данные от сервиса?

Tags: angular

Есть репозиторий:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationExistingRelationShipsRepository {
    private documents: ApplicationExistingRelationShips[] = [];

    constructor(private applicationExistingRelationShipsService: ApplicationExistingRelationShipsService) {
        applicationExistingRelationShipsService.get().subscribe((documents) => {
            this.documents = documents;
        });
    }

    getDocuments() {
        return this.documents;
    }
}
```

Использую его в компоненте:

```
constructor(private applicationExistingRelationShipsRepository: ApplicationExistingRelationShipsRepository) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.documents = this.applicationExistingRelationShipsRepository.getDocuments();
}
```

Данные в репозитории точно есть и приходят в переменную `this.documents`.

Почему в компоненте я получаю пустой массив?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что валью прилетает позже, но думаю проблема к этому времени уже не актуальна. Решением будет создать `BehaviourSubject` на уровне сервиса, прокидовать после гета инфу в сабжект и подписаться на стороне компоненты.